# Access a random number in an animation

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I've been having a lot of fun animating armatures, but I've ran into a problem.
I've been using the NLA editor to play around with repeating animations.

Let's say I have an object, that can rotate along the z axis:

[image: Arrow]

My goal would be, to have the arrow slowly rotate to a random direction every time the action gets played by the NLA editor. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!